# How to response percentage of file upload process in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to response percentage of my total file upload process.

I use `XmlHttpRequest` to post upload file to server by `async`. But I have a problem getting the progress percentage from .net core controller.

This is my API method.

```
[HttpPost]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterBlockedFile(IFormFile file, string text)
{
     long size = file.Length;
     string filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();


     //Connect and Upload to DB Logic
     //~~~~


     //I always want to return real percentage of all processes.
     return Ok(new { count = 1, size, filePath });
}
```

In my plan, client will upload the file and above server controller's method will connect and upload to db server. And if this all progresses are finish, then it can call 100% finished.

But this API method is always called after the file was already received. The client side's `xml-http` request always can know about just amount of its sent bytes. But it is not a real percentage.

All references and examples are just for client side's send bytes progress.

It there have any easy solution to solve this?

Comment: Here is an example that has client and backend code: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-achieve-upload-cdfe216c

Comment: @SergiuMuresan Thanks but I already saw that. It is just for client side(sended progress). It can not real progressing from server.

Comment: What is the size of the file and does your endpoint 'RegisterBlockFile' does some data processing or plain upload?